# Create map of lists from Spring config in Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, yaml

I am trying to create a object of type `Map<String, List<String>>` in a `Spring Boot` application written in `Kotlin`.

I am able to create a map from config, and am also able to create a list from config, but when I try and combine the two I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myConfiguration': Could not bind properties to MyConfiguration (prefix=, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My `Configuration Object`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
class MyConfiguration {
   var myNewMap: Map<String, List<String>>? = null
}
```

My `Configuration yml`:

```
---
myNewMap:
   firstKey:
     - 2
     - 4
   secondKey:
     - 2
```

Is this possible with the way Spring reads in configuration? Or is the only way to create a simple Map with the values as a comma separated string, and turn it into a list in my application?

`Kotlin: 1.2.0`
`Spring Boot: 1.5.6.RELEASE`

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me when the map is inside a "prefix" which is recommended for spring boot configurations.

My yml:

```
apiconfig:
  myNewMap:
    firstKey:
      - 2
      - 4
    secondKey:
      - 2
```

and my config class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "apiconfig")
class ApiConfiguration {
    var myNewMap: Map<String, List<String>>? = null
}
```

usage class:

```
@RestController
class Apis(@Autowired private val apiConfiguration : ApiConfiguration) {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    fun test(): String {
        apiConfiguration.myNewMap
        return "test"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For whoever still having this, the `@Component` interface won't help you, you need `@ConstructorBinding`.

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "apiconfig")
class ApiConfiguration {
    var myNewMap: Map<String, List<String>>? = null
}
```